# Simple way to find 3 largest values for a given column with corresponding value in another column in my own format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a DataFrame...

```
data = {'PVOL': [190, 105, 100, 150, 100, 170], 'STKS': [2000, 2500, 3000, 3500, 4000, 4500],
'CVOL': [64, 179, 98, 281, 86, 90]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now I want to find 3 largest values for all other columns(PVOL, CVOL...etc as my df may have multiple other columns too) and their corresponding value of column STKS in following manner (as string/print):

```
PVOL - 2000[190], 4500[170], 3500[150]
CVOL - 3500[281], 2500[179], 3000[98]
```

I tried following to get 2 largest values in df format ...

```
columns_name = list(df.columns)
columns_name.remove('STKS')
data_dict = {}
for col in columns_name:
      temp=[]
      data=df.sort_values(col, ascending=False)[:2][[col,'STKS']].values
      for row in data:
        temp.append(row[1])
        temp.append(row[0])
      data_dict[col]=temp

new_df1=pd.DataFrame(data_dict,index="STK VOL STK VOL".split())
new_df1.set_axis(["PVOL", "CVOL"], axis='columns', inplace=True)
Vol_df = new_df1[["PVOL", "CVOL"]]
print(Vol_df)
```

Is there any simple method to do that plz ??? I also read about..

```
df.nlargest()
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the exact expected output?

Comment: @mozway, sir plz here is my another question.....https://stackoverflow.com/q/77550481/22382314

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a custom function with [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html):

```
def f(s, n=3):
    x = s.nlargest(n)
    return ', '.join(f'{a}[{b}]' for a,b in zip(x.index, x))

df.set_index('STKS').apply(f)
```

Output:

```
PVOL    2000[190], 4500[170], 3500[150]
CVOL     3500[281], 2500[179], 3000[98]
dtype: object
```

If you want strings:

```
for key, col in df.set_index('STKS').items():
    x = col.nlargest(3)
    s = ', '.join(f'{a}[{b}]' for a,b in zip(x.index, x))
    print(f'{key} - {s}')
```

Output:

```
PVOL - 2000[190], 4500[170], 3500[150]
CVOL - 3500[281], 2500[179], 3000[98]
```

##### only for a subset of columns:

```
cols = ['CCHOI', 'PIV']

for key, col in df.set_index('STKS')[cols].items():
    x = col.nlargest(3)
    s = ', '.join(f'{a}[{b}]' for a,b in zip(x.index, x))
    print(f'{key} - {s}')
```

Comment: @BrijeshChaurasia you're welcome. I'll edit your question to clarify that you expect a string

Comment: Sir if my DataFrame has few other columns too and I want this for only one or two columns then what ??? More clearly if my DataFrame has 9 columns as PEOI, PCHOI, PVOL, PIV, STKS, CIV, CVOL, CCHOI, CEOI and I need only for CCHOI column ??? or CCHOI and PIV column only.

Comment: then define a list of columns `cols = ['CCHOI', 'PIV']` and runs the loop on `df.set_index('STKS')[cols].items()`

Comment: Thanks. This one made my all queries to get finished.

Comment: sir one last query plz... what if I want to write something else at the place of keys ? Let's say Support & Resistance at the place of PVOL & CVOL respectively.

Comment: Then use a dictionary to map the replacements: `dic = {'PVOL': 'Support', 'CVOL': 'Resistance'}` and `print(f'{dic[key]} - {s}')`

Answer (score 1):

Yes. you can use **nlargest** method like this :

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'PVOL': [190, 105, 100, 150, 100, 170],
        'STKS': [2000, 2500, 3000, 3500, 4000, 4500],
        'CVOL': [64, 179, 98, 281, 86, 90]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

result = {}

for col in df.columns:
    if col != 'STKS':
        top_values = df.nlargest(3, col)
        result[col] = list(zip(top_values['STKS'], top_values[col]))

result_df = pd.DataFrame(result)
print(result_df)
```

**Output :**

```
          PVOL         CVOL
0  (2000, 190)  (3500, 281)
1  (4500, 170)  (2500, 179)
2  (3500, 150)   (3000, 98)
```

[EDIT] :

To achieve the specific output format you want

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'PVOL': [190, 105, 100, 150, 100, 170],
        'STKS': [2000, 2500, 3000, 3500, 4000, 4500],
        'CVOL': [64, 179, 98, 281, 86, 90]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

result = {}

for col in df.columns:
    if col != 'STKS':
        top_values = df.nlargest(3, col)
        result[col] = ', '.join([f"{stk}[{val}]" for stk, val in zip(top_values['STKS'], top_values[col])])

result_df = pd.Series(result)
print(result_df)
```

**Output :**

```
PVOL    2000[190], 4500[170], 3500[150]
CVOL     3500[281], 2500[179], 3000[98]
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but output format is not what I needed. Plz can you update your answer?? I don't need output as DataFrame.

Comment: i update my answer